# Weblogic 12.1.3 console gives 503 error

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I am getting this error whenever I am trying to open console for weblogic. It was working fine a few days ago.

```
<A problem occurred while dispatching the servlet request.
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: <openjpa-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1445923 nonfatal user error> kodo.jdo.UserException: This operation cannot be performed while a Transaction is active.
        at weblogic.application.services.BackgroundDeploymentService$OnDemandDeployer.deploy(BackgroundDeploymentService.java:173)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.OnWebUriDemandDeploymentProvider$OnWebUriDemandListener.OnDemandURIAccessed(OnWebUriDemandDeploymentProvider.java:46)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.OnDemandManager.loadOnDemandURI(OnDemandManager.java:113)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.MuxableSocketHTTP.handleOnDemandContext(MuxableSocketHTTP.java:210)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpConnectionHandler.dispatch(HttpConnectionHandler.java:647)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: <openjpa-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1445923 nonfatal user error> kodo.jdo.UserException: This operation cannot be performed while a Transaction is active.
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.close(BrokerImpl.java:4087)
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.close(DelegatingBroker.java:1298)
        at kodo.jdo.PersistenceManagerImpl.close(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:958)
        at com.bea.security.providers.xacml.store.BasePolicyStore.setPolicy(BasePolicyStore.java:757)
        at com.bea.security.providers.xacml.store.BasePolicyStore.setPolicy(BasePolicyStore.java:615)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

[Error in IE on opening console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ac6yv.png)

**All the other applications deployed on it are working fine.**

Comment: did u find the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

One of my clients is having the same problem but on WLS12.2.1.4.

So far, I have found 2 hints that could help you:

- the embeddedLDAP is corrupted as described by *kodo.jdo.UserException: Exception on Running OIM Patch_weblogic script (Doc ID 1108693.1)*. Solved after regenerating the embeddedLDAP for this particular managed server.
- the server is affected by bug 20717082. The patch 20717082 is available for WLS10.3.6, WLS12.1.2, and WLS12.1.3.

Hope some of these options work for you. On my end, I'll keep on investigating.